# Passing Variable inside a Python Payload

Tags: python, http, request

I've a python script which runs perfectly when I pass hard coded value in Payload. But when I try to pass variable, it prints the variable as is. Can you please help me?

**Below is what it looks like:**

```
subRegion = 'CEEI'
        payloadNew = "{  \r\n   \"customFields\":[  \r\n      {  \r\n         \"name\":\"MYLC_User_Region\",\r\n         \"value\":\"Europe\"\r\n      },\r\n      {  \r\n         \"name\":\"MYLC_User_SubRegion\",\r\n         \"value\": + subRegion + \r\n      }\r\n   ]\r\n}"
        print(payloadNew)
```

and output comes like this

```
{  
   "customFields":[  
      {  
         "name":"MYLC_User_Region",
         "value":"Europe"
      },
      {  
         "name":"MYLC_User_SubRegion",
         "value": + subRegion + 
      }
   ]
}
```

But What I'm trying to achieve is

```
{  
   "customFields":[  
      {  
         "name":"MYLC_User_Region",
         "value":"Europe"
      },
      {  
         "name":"MYLC_User_SubRegion",
         "value": "CEEI"
      }
   ]
}
```

Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: try string formatting. Google `format` or `f-strings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mis interpreted the problem on my previous answer. You need to end the first part of the string in order to concate the new string.

```
subRegion = "\"CEEI\""
payloadNew = "{  \r\n   \"customFields\":[  \r\n      {  \r\n         \"name\":\"MYLC_User_Region\",\r\n         \"value\":\"Europe\"\r\n      },\r\n      {  \r\n         \"name\":\"MYLC_User_SubRegion\",\r\n         \"value\": " + subRegion + "\r\n      }\r\n   ]\r\n}"
print(payloadNew)
```

Alternatively you can use string formatting as mentioned above.